# Lock transformation in local coordinate system

Tags: transforms, axis

I want to lock the transformation to certain axes only, but when I just lock the axes in the *Transform* panel, they seem to lock global coordinates, even when *Transform Orientation* is set to *Local*.

[image: GIF]

Note that locking the axes removes the arrows from the *local* gizmo, which makes this all the more confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what the *Transform Location* locks are for, they lock the objects on the *Global* axis, the fact that you switch the *Transformation Orientation* from *Global* to *Local* won't change it.

If you want to constraint an object on its local axis, use a *Limit Location* constraint, switch the *Convert* to *Local Space* and choose on which axis you want it to be constrained.

[image]

Comment: Not super convenient but it is a working solution.

Comment: One question though: If the locks are for locking on the global axes, why does it also remove the local axes from the gizmo in the viewport? What's the use case for that?